# how to write and get all the xml elements in same level with same name using JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom, xmlnode

my xml file is as follows

```
<lexicon>
  <lexiconElement>
    <word>xxxx</word>
    <tag>NN
      <frequancy>3</frequancy>
    </tag>
    <tag>VB
      <frequancy>2</frequancy>
    </tag>
  </lexiconElement>
</lexicon>
```

i need to know how to append many  elements to same level in the same xml file when updating using JDOM and how to read those elements with the same name in same level using JDOM???

Comment: Can you update your question with input and out xml both. Assuming the given xml is your input. How your updated xml should look like.

Comment: update can happen in few ways.
1. add new <tag> elements to xml.
2.Update the text between <frequancy> .
3.update the text between <word>

Comment: Can you provide a sample. What kind of outcome you are expecting to your given xml

Comment: update can happen in few ways. 1. add new <tag> elements to xml. 2.Update the text between <frequancy> . 3.update the text between <word>

Comment: i need to know how to get the texts between all <tag> elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
try {

            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
            File xmlFile = new File("D:\\your_file.xml");

            Document doc = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
            Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();

            Element lexiconElement = rootNode.getChild("lexiconElement");

            // 1. add new <tag> elements to xml
            Element newTag = new Element("your_new_tag").setText("your_new_tag_value");
            lexiconElement.addContent(newTag);

            // 2. Update the text between <frequancy> in perticular tag
            //lexiconElement.getChild("tag").getChild("frequancy").setText("9");

            // 2. Update the text between <frequancy> in all tag
            List<Element> list = lexiconElement.getChildren("tag");
            for(Element elm : list){
                elm.getChild("frequancy").setText("324");
            }

            // 3. Update the text between <word>
            lexiconElement.getChild("word").setText("yyyy");

            XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

            xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileWriter("D:\\your_file.xml"));

            System.out.println("*********Done************");
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```